# PIC16F1717 with XC8 v1.43, variable for keypad presses

Tags: c, microcontroller, keypad, xc8

I have a 4x3 matrix keypad connected to PORT B (RB1-RB7) of a PIC16F1717. I scan for keypad presses by setting each of the rows high in turn, and reading the column values. The key pressed can be decoded by matching the row and column. I am debouncing with a short delay:

```
while(1)
{
    //scan for key presses
    __delay_ms(10);
    ROW1 = 1;
    ROW2 = 0;
    ROW3 = 0;
    ROW4 = 0;
    if (COL1 == 1)
    {
        __delay_ms(100);
        if (COL1 == 1)
        {
            key = 1;
            keyCount = keyCount ++ 1;
        }
    }
    else if (COL2 == 1)
    {
        __delay_ms(100);
        if (COL2 == 1)
        {
            key = 2;
            keyCount = keyCount + 1;

        }
    }
    //and so on for the other rows and columns
```

The two variable key and keyCount keep track of which key has been pressed, and the number of keys pressed, respectively. When 4 keys have been pressed, I want to execute the following code:

```
    if (keyCount == 4)
    {
        LED = 1;
        __delay_ms(500);
        LED = 0;
        __delay_ms(500);
        LED = 1;
        __delay_ms(500);
        LED = 0;
        __delay_ms(500);
        LED = 1;
        __delay_ms(500);
        servoDemo();
        __delay_ms(500);
        LED = 0;
        keyCount = 0;

    }
```

This is also in the while(1) loop inside the main function. The problem I am having is that incrementing the keyCount does not work. Previously, I tried keyCount++ and it worked, but before that this wouldn't work either. I tried debugging by setting keyCount = 4 instead of incrementing it by one, and it worked.

Both variables were declared (and initialised) inside the main function, but outside the while(1) loop. Also, I defined the following:

```
//pin definitions
//////////////////////////
#define ROW1 PORTBbits.RB2
#define ROW2 PORTBbits.RB7
#define ROW3 PORTBbits.RB6
#define ROW4 PORTBbits.RB4

#define COL1 PORTBbits.RB3
#define COL2 PORTBbits.RB1
#define COL3 PORTBbits.RB5

#define SERVOSIG PORTDbits.RD0
#define LED PORTDbits.RD1
```

Comment: First it would be better to use loops for the row and col thing. You also do not count the edges of the buttons, which is maybe what you want. Do you have any interrupts? Maybe it would be helpful to post the complete code, especially the initialization of the registers.

Comment: Here are the register initialisations:

Comment: `//disable analog
    ANSELA = 0x00;
    ANSELB = 0x00;
    ANSELC = 0x00;
    ANSELD = 0x00;
    
    //set column pins as inputs
    TRISBbits.TRISB3 = 1;
    TRISBbits.TRISB1 = 1;
    TRISBbits.TRISB5 = 1;
    
    //set row pins as outputs
    TRISBbits.TRISB2 = 0;
    TRISBbits.TRISB7 = 0;
    TRISBbits.TRISB6 = 0;
    TRISBbits.TRISB4 = 0;
    
    //set LED pins as outputs
    TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 0;
    TRISDbits.TRISD1 = 0;`

Comment: I haven't used interrupts for this. I see how using loops would make the key press decoding code more compact. Is the variable keyCount perhaps incrementing for as long as the key is pressed? I don't think that's how it works since it's just an if statement, but I really can't think of any explanation for why this is happening. If this is the case, then edge detection sounds like a reasonable solution. How would I go about detecting a positive edge, say?

Comment: Yes it is how it works. You enter the if statement every time as long as the key is pressed. An example of edge detection would be to remember the old values of the keys and compare it with the new ones.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. The if statement will be entered as long as the key is pressed, I was just getting confused by the fact that it's an if statement, not a while statement. I will try the method you suggested, by looking for changes in the key state by comparing to previous values, rather than the looking for the "high" state.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have no edge detection on your keys. That means that as long as you press a key the if statement is entered every loop cycle. Here is a small example which may give you the basic idea how to implement a loop detection.

```
int key[12];
int key_old[12];

read_keys(key); //function that reads the keys in

while(1)
{
    memcpy(key_old, key, 12*sizeof(key[0])); //copy key to key_old
    read_keys(key); //function that reads the keys in

    for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        if(key[i] && !key_old[i])
        {
            //positive edge on key i
        }
    }

    __delay_ms(50); //Debouncing
}
```

This code is not perfect but should give a basic idea as mentioned.